# What does buying tokens do?

Tags: scramble-with-friends

If you tap the "Get Tokens" button, you'll have the option of buying between 16 and 500 tokens for real money, but I'm confused as to how this works.

By default you only start with 15 tokens which replenish at a rate of 1 every 20 minutes. If you buy 16 tokens, do they start getting used up when the initial 15 are gone? Does it add an additional 16 coins which replenish over time, or are they one-time use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tokens which replenish are set; you cannot increase the maximum amount. Buying more tokens through in-app purchases are one-time use.

For example, say I buy 50 tokens, and along with my 15 default, I have 65. Once my 15 are used, I can use my 50 tokens to keep playing and avoid the wait. However, I can only recharge 15 tokens.